# Show pop up only first time user login in express framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Express the Node.JS framework, and cookies for authentication.

How can I show a pop up for the user's first login only?

Comment: You could store a cookie stating that the popup has been shown before. If this cookie is not present, display the popup and add the cookie. Without your code, I can't really be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same technique from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54284535/10221765):

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("firstTime")) {
    localStorage.setItem("firstTime", "true");
    showPopUp();
}
```