# How do I make a webpage only available once?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a webpage that only new users can see if a returning viewer returns he will be redirected to another webpage I found this on stackoverflow but I am unable to figure it out.

I have made a HTML and CSS page which showcases the features of my web app. I want this page to load only for new visitors. If a returning visitor visits my domain, it should redirect him/her to the web platform. Essentially, the new user should see "Landing Page" while a returning user should be redirected to "Web Platform"

The answer was

[How do I make a web page show up only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284510/how-do-i-make-a-web-page-show-up-only-once/54284535)

I am unable to use it because I don't know what to do and how to create localstorage

Comment: What have you tried?  We can help better if you [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: you only have 1 reliable solution, make them sign in. All other solutions like local storage, cookies, serverside sessions or by IP address are unreliable as they are ephemeral

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP code to make a webpage only available once with SESSION and log.

Comment: Can you give me a code which can help me out with it?

Comment: use Mysql and Http agent and php session