# How to only display onload modal once per visit per user

Tags: jquery

I know you can user session storage to only display an onload modal once. Not sure on syntax or where to add it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#featureGuide').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Bootstrap Modal First time page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596429/display-bootstrap-modal-first-time-page-loads)

Answer (score 2):

Set the value in local storage after login (Or when you want to show).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    var modelShown = localStorage.getItem('modelShown');
    if(modelShown != 'YES'){
      $('#featureGuide').modal('show');
      localStorage.setItem('modelShown', 'YES');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Clear the local storage on logout.

```
localStorage.removeItem('modelShown');
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I actually decided to use session storage rather than local storage but works the same :)