# On refresh open modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an API to get a ticker price and its being displayed through a modal. Now what I did was add a button that says "Get Current Prices":

```
<button onClick="window.location.reload()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Get Current Prices</button>
```

When you click it refreshes the page successfully but I want it to open the modal again. I did find something on stack overflow where on page load it opens a modal. It almost works but I only want it to open if the "Get Current Prices" button has been clicked.

Link to the other SO question: [Launch Bootstrap Modal on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233550/launch-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load)

Comment: Use localStorage or sessionStorage to store the click, and then make a comparison against that value on page load, if true, show the modal, if not true, don't show the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest you refresh your page using an ajax call rather than reloading the entire page to refresh a ticker.

If you really need to reload the page then pass a url param which you can check for.

You'll probably have to use window.location.href = "MyUrl?openModal=true"

You can check for this value in the window.onLoad event and open your modal dialog based on this value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I would be able to do something more effecienatly with AJAX and rails. I have a variable called @buy =  api_call so I will ask another question but on how to update a rails varaible with ajax. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Agree Ajax for the win!!