# Modals fail to refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have two modals on my page that I need to refresh, but for some reason every time I close out of them and open them back up they are not updated, despite not even being loaded until the buttons are clicked.

How can I make it so that every time the buttons are clicked the pages that the modals are calling are refreshed?

This is the code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


    <a class="button border" data-toggle="modal" href="page1.php" data-target="#myModa2">Page 1</a>
    <a class="button border" data-toggle="modal" href="page2.php" data-target="#myModa3">Page 2</a>


        <div class="modal fade" id="myModa2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>          


        <div class="modal fade" id="myModa3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On refresh open modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723106/on-refresh-open-modal)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378720/bootstrap-3-with-remote-modal#18387625