# How to make modal dialog open at page load in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

It's easy to show a modal dialog with javascript in Bootstrap.

But how to make the modal open at page load without the need of a `document.ready` function or a body `onload` function?

My need is to load a page and have the modal allready opened.
I don't want a delay nor a transition effect when the page load.
I want that the modal is opened at startup.

I look the modal.js a little bit and tried adding `class="modal-open"` on the body with no effect.

```
<div class="modal in" id="journalModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         body
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Is it possible?
How to do it ?

Comment: I guess this fiddle is pretty fine http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/sj9EQ/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When modal becomes visible, Bootstrap adds `.in` class to  the it's container. So you can add a rule in your css as below and add the same class to modal - which you want to be visible at page load.

**CSS**

```
.modal.in {
   display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal in">visible on page load.</div>
```

But these will not bring the modal backdrop in place. So you gotta keep those also in bottom of page:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I just had to remove the fade class for the modal backdrop not to be totally dark. `<div class="modal-backdrop in"></div>`

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at this [Launch Bootstrap Modal on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234834) from [Andres Ilich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680398/andres-ilich)

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The author specifically asked for a solution that doesn't require using 'the need of a `document.ready` function or a body `onload` function'. I consider `$(window).load` to be much the same as `onload`, hence the downvote.

Comment: nevertheless useful for some - also $(window).load(... has to be replaced by $(windows).on('load', ....)  for modern versions of jQuery. to get rid of "fade" effect just remove the "fade" class from the modal