# django bootstrap show modal on load and use fade

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using a modal for a small form but I am bumping into a problem

I want my background to be faded when opening it and also when the page is loaded with it already shown (in case of form errors)

```
<div class="modal {% if form.errors %}show{% endif %}" id="ApiModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
```

The modal will be shown, but the background is not faded anymore. Now when i user fade together with show in the class.

```
<div class="modal {% if form.errors %}show fade{% endif %}" id="ApiModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
```

The modal is opened (page seems blocked) but it isn't shown anywhere

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch Bootstrap Modal on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233550/launch-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load)

Comment: Already looked at that one. But as far as i tried the solutions it doesnt work

Comment: In your sample code, you are checking for errors on two different forms... do you have two different modal windows? or is that a typo?

Comment: Oops thats a mistake in my post here. its not the case in my code. ill correct it

Comment: So, just to understand your last statement, if you set `class="show fade"` the modal window is **not** shown on page load?

Comment: Well it is shown but hidden (i think) the page get locked like something hidden is in front. I tried changing the aria-hidden to false but yields the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69236/discussion-between-brandon-and-hans-de-jong).

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ApiModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Seems this problem is not solvable with just bootstrap classes (not any of the other examples worked