# on load open model popup using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

model is opening  on click :

```
 <a href="#" data-remodal-target="test" >test</a>
```

my model code is :

```
 <div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="test">
    <h3 class="modal-middle-heading">Buy</h3>
    <p>Please select your desired gift city.</p>
    <form class="login-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search City" />
    </form>
    <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

How can I open model on load ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233550/launch-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [remodal](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal), you could just programmatically open the model on your `onload` event. Something like this:

```
  window.onload = function () {                                                
    $('[data-remodal-id=test]').remodal().open();                              
  };
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m0vkye9d/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#test').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```