# Modal Show on page load

Tags: php, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap modal work with an anchor tag if we click on it then modal appears. I want it to appear it while we load a page. What should I do. Here is my code.

```
    <a class="popup-trigger" href="#my-popup">Open Popup</a>
    <div id="my-popup" class="popup">My Popup</div>
```

Now if we click on this first anchor tag the modal will be open. I want this to open automatically while loading a page. Thanks.

Comment: when the page gets load,show the modal using `$("#my-popup").modal(show)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Bootstrap Modal on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233550/launch-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually open a modal :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my-popup').modal({
            show: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my-popup').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Documentation : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is on document ready.

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('#my-popup').modal('show');
});
```

This basically shows the modal without needed to click it

An example can be seen here of what you can do:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api