# Bootstrap modal won't open on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, pageload

I have a modal that I am successfully opening with a button:

```
<button onclick="content()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal">Save</button>

<form action="addPage.php" method="post">
  <div class="modal fade" id="my_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="savePageLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="savePageLabel">Page Details:</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But I'm trying to have it open on page load instead and it won't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#my_Modal').modal('show');
}); 
</script>
```

I feel like it should be the right syntax and everything, but I can't understand why the button will open it but page load and document.ready won't?

UPdate:

My includes

```
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.js-master/instafeed.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Have you included jquery library file? Which bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: Just updated with all of my javascript includes. Using bootstrap 4.0.0. And my other javascript functions are working

Comment: did you get any issues in console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Bootstrap Modal on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233550/launch-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, even with the wrong ID (capital M).

See your code working (chrome)... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/njd7vuLx/

Are you loading the bootstrap js and query properly?

Your code...

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#my_Modal').modal('show');
});
```

Screenshot of the jsfiddle working for me with your original code.

[image]

Comment: I still can't get it, regardless of IDs. Can you see an issue in my includes?

Comment: Like I say i just used your code as is in jsfiddle with the bootstrap 4 and jquery framework. And it works, so there must be an error your side perhaps or your not loading the jquery or js properly. Does any other bootstrap js components work on your page?

Comment: I'm using chrome and the modal launches for me in the jsfiddle. https://imgur.com/a/wtVejF1

Comment: Everything else, bootstrap and JS, works fine. But that's what's weird because when I load your fiddle it doesn't show either

Comment: What browser you using?

Comment: chrome and firefox

Comment: So weird that the fiddle doesn't work for you. Not really sure man. Keep digging. Try setting up a basic raw test modal from the bs modal docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/

Comment: So use php to include my menu file, <?php include 'menu.php'?> and when I remove t his it works

Answer (score 1):

The Id you are using is wrong.
Try this:

```
$('#my_modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Ah I didn't catch that, but it's still not working unfortunately

Comment: Sometimes the "$(window).load" is not working correctly.
Are you sure the element is there, at the time code is run?

Comment: That's not working either. There's got to be something weird going on

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake

its **"#my_modal" not "#my_Modal"**

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('#my_modal').modal('show');
    }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: It's still not loading for some reason. Is there an issue in the order of my includes?

Comment: try placing teather.min.js below the jquery-3.3.1.min.js and also try "on" function like $(document).on('load', function(){
    $('#my_modal').modal('show');
    });

Comment: Ok so I include my menu.php file on every page. When I remove <?include 'menu.php'?> it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```js
$(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#my_modal').modal('show');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="content()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal">Save</button>

<form action="addPage.php" method="post">
  <div class="modal fade" id="my_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="savePageLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="savePageLabel">Page Details:</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
But I'm trying to have it open on page load instead and it won't work:
```

Comment: do you get any error in console, does you firewall allow `CDN` try opening https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: No but I may have found the issue. I'm using startblocks and endblocks in order to template the page with my included menu. When I remove those it works