# Redirect to registration bootstrap model in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am using the following code in my controller for redirecting to login page if a guest user clicks button for uploading a product. Now I have created bootstrap model for login and registration. I want to pop-up the modal if user click button.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except('index', 'show');
    }
```

Login and Register Button

```
@guest
   <li class="list-inline-item">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signIn" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</button>
   </li>
   @if (Route::has('register'))
     <li class="list-inline-item">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }} </button>
      </li>
   @endif
```

Bootstrap Modal

```
<div class="modal" id="signIn">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">SignIn</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    &times;
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                            name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus />

                        @error('email')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
                        <input id="password" type="password"
                            class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required
                            autocomplete="current-password">

                        @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                            Sign In
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With just blade? Or in Vue? In blade you'd have to do redirect and based on a variable show the modal on page load, by setting it to visible.

Comment: Yeah I am using just blade. I have edited my question

Comment: then you should include the modal in the view and use a something like ```{{ $showLoginForm ? ' visible' : '' }}``` (or whatever class bootstrap uses to make the modal visible) in the class of the modal, to show it.

Comment: it is in the header and I have included the header in most of the views

Comment: both button and the model are in the same template

Comment: then all you have to do is make it visible

Comment: How do I make it visible?

Comment: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17444580/4311857

Comment: okay, will try that one