# Bootstrap modal visible by default with HTML

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make a Bootstrap modal visible by default without JavaScript? I tried with `show`, but it doesn't work.

```html
<div class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="update-info-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{ message|nl2br }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-{{ label }}" data-dismiss="modal">{{ 'modal.language.close' | trans }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you inspect the HTML of an opened modal you'll see the class you need to add is `in`.  If you want the page background to also work you need to manually add a `<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>`, and add `modal-open` class to the `<body>`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17444580.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding the following code inside the style.

```
.modal.show {
  display: block;
}
```

However, this is not a recommended method. Instead, you can trigger the modal right after the first load of the page.

Comment: There is no part in Bootstrap 5 where this definition is made directly. You can check.